# Viewing a circle from different angles, can I find these two angles?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I am looking into a circle rotated with respect to the line of sight by angle $\alpha$ around the vertical axis and then and $\beta$ around the horizontal axis, so instead of a circle, I see an ellipse. I know the ratio $a$ between major and minor axis of the ellipse, as well as the angle $\theta$ that the major axis of the ellipse makes with the horizon, but the size of the circle and distance to it are not know with a useful precision.

If the circle is rotated around the vertical axis only ($\beta=0$), $\theta=90$ (vertical) and probably I can use the formula of the cross section of the cylinder to find $\alpha$ as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336305/cross-section-of-a-cylinder); $\beta=0$. The similar solution works when rotating around the horizontal axis only.

By moving a dish plate in front of my eyes, I see that when $\beta=45, \alpha=45$ the major axis of the ellipse goes at angle, probably $\theta=+45$ or $\theta=-45$, depending on how exactly do I rotate, while aspect ratio $a$ shrinks. Is it possible to find the two rotation angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the visible shape of the ellipse?

Comment: Which type of projection? Parallel or perspective?

Comment: It seems that you have 3 unknowns and two equations - for a given radius you could find two angels (Based on the ellipse axis)